# "Warning: It is not yet possible to assign complex types to properties" in array foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have this SimpleXMLElement Object.

```
 [prices] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [term] => 0.5
                            [price] => 35
                            [currency] => EUR
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [term] => 1
                            [price] => 60
                            [currency] => EUR
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [term] => 2
                            [price] => 50
                            [currency] => EUR
                        )
                )
         )
)
```

Trying create `$term[]` array ...

```
foreach($xmlData->prices->price as $term) {
            $term[] = array(
            'term' => (string)$term->term,
            'price' => (string)$term->price,
            'currency' => (string)$term->currency
            );
        }
```

But getting **WARNING : It is not yet possible to assign complex types to properties in** this string: `$term[] = array(`

How to solve this problem?

SOLVED by changing `$term[] = array(` to `$terms[] = array(`

Comment: At a glance, you have quite a few mentions of `$term` which are probably overwriting each other.

Comment: Try - `$output[] = array(`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes you are right. Seems I need to make a little brake with coding... :D and to take a rest little bit.